# Android Studio on click button after a splash screen and a main screen

Tags: java, android

Hi I need help to know where to put these code

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this, Gallery.class));
        }
    });
```

on my android studio code.

Here is my Android studio Code:

```
public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);


        Thread logoTimer = new Thread() {

            public void run() {

                try {

                    int logoTimer = 0;

                    while (logoTimer < 3000) {

                        sleep(100);

                        logoTimer = logoTimer + 100;

                    }
                    ;

                    startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class));

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                    e.printStackTrace();

                } finally {

                    finish();

                }

            }


        };

        logoTimer.start();


    }




    }
```

I tried putting the code after the codes for the splash screen but it ain't working, I also tried putting it before the code for the splash screen but my app ain't running. There is no error found but the app when I play it on the AVD, the app is not running (My App)

Comment: You should put this code from wherever you want to move to the gallery screen.

Comment: Put that code after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);` inside `onCreate`